# Get Active Window ID in Hex not Decimal

Tags: wmctrl

How to get the window ID of the focus(active) window in Hex ?

Comment: Get it in decimal and convert to hex?

Answer (score 9):

Try this hack:

```
wmctrl -lp | grep $(xprop -root | grep _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | head -1 | \
    awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/,//' | sed 's/^0x/0x0/')
```

For example:

```
$ wmctrl -lp | grep $(xprop -root | grep _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | head -1 | \
>     awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/,//' | sed 's/^0x/0x0/')

0x07600006  0 19051  maythuxPC Gnome Terminal
```

0x07600006 is the hex of active window which is the terminal in my case.

To be sure let's get it in decimal:

```
$ xdotool getactivewindow 
123731974
```

Now convert from decimal to hex:

```
$ printf 0x%x 123731974
0x7600006
```

It's the same.

Comment: Dear Maythux thank you for your fast reply. May I ask how can I receive only the hex ID , in order to use it inside my c++ program?

Comment: Please change your code `sed 's/^0x/0x0/'`  to `xargs printf "0x%08x"`. It has a bug when the hexadecimal is rounded down when it begins with `0x00`.

Comment: Why do we need `sed 's/^0x/0x0/'` or `xargs printf "0x%08x"`?

Answer (score 1):

Gives you 3 seconds time to change the window focus and
prints afterwards the hexadecimal PID:

```
~$ sleep 3; printf 0x%x $(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use printf to convert decimal to hex.
Eg. to get the window id of active window in hex use

```
xdotool getactivewindow | xargs -I{} printf '%x\n' {}
```